# Merging data with OneToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have two entities with OneToMany relation ship

Resource.java

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="resource", orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Skills> skills = new HashSet<Skills>();
```

and the other entity is Skills.java

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "RESOURCE_CODE", unique = false, nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_resource_primary_skills_map_resource_code"))
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true, targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED, modifiedColumnName = "RESOURCE_CODE_MOD")
private Resource resource;
```

I would add/update/delete skills of resource in one-go.
for that i am trying to clear all existing skills and adding a fresh-set of skills

```
resourceObject.getSkills().clear();
resourceObject.getSkills().addAll(skills);
```

add /delete are working fine. but update is not working.
i see below exception

```
 a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

i tried entityManager.flush and new transactions , but nothing worked

Comment: How do you update the skills?

Comment: I get the updated skill  in set. I clear the existing set add fresh set

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do that by updating existing set instead of clearing every thing.  That added lots of if loops things are done.

The root cause is, the child entity do not have auto generated primary key,its unique key based on data. So as per flush operation order insert happens before deletion. so unique identifier already exists for the operation we do(whatever order we perform like delete first,insert next).

Two solutions
1) add a primary key(which will be different for newly added entities)
OR
2) Update the existing child entities(not adding new childs)